# Is it possible to check in background if an android/iOS device is in use at the moment?

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to determine if a device (non-rooted) is in use at the moment, even if my app is not in the foreground? Precisely "in use" means the user made touch events in the last 5 seconds or display is on.

If so, what specific rights are required?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a rigorous definition of what "is in use" means.

Comment: thanks for helping! i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "in use" means the user made touch events in the last 5 seconds

In Android, that's not practical, short of writing your own custom ROM.

> or display is on

In Android, you can find out [if the device is in an "interactive" mode or not](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive()). This does not strictly align with screen-on/screen-off, as the whole notion of screen-on/screen-off has pretty much fallen by the wayside.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in iOS? And do you have alternative ideas to checking if a user is actually holding the device in his hand and really interacting with it for older android apis, like api 9?

Comment: @ChrisYoung: "Is there an equivalent in iOS?" -- I have no idea. "And do you have alternative ideas to checking if a user is actually holding the device in his hand and really interacting with it for older android apis, like api 9?" -- `isScreenOn()` works back to API Level 7. Bear in mind that [~0.2% of active Play Store ecosystem devices run less than API Level 10](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, android security model would not allow you to record touches if your app in not in the foreground.

There are some crude workarounds like overlaying a transparent screen to record touches. Not sure if these work now though.

Comment: Oh, you could rig up a transparent screen to record touches. However, you would *consume* those touch events, meaning that the device would be useless. And it requires a nasty-sounding permission. And on Android 6.0, it requires the user agree through a separate process to grant your app that permission.